# Products, Add To Shopping Cart with cookie-value not showing in ListView

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm Tryring to add products to cart without User login in my app. Then If user LOGIN it needs to show the same products which is user add his cart without Login. But I'm facing problem when passing a random integer value from SharedPreferences. I think its changing when the app restarts.

Am I doing somthing wrong?

For that I 1st generate random integer number.

*Function call to generate random number and saved in `SharedPreferences`*

```
funForCookie(Random().nextInt(90)+10);
```

*funForCookie() function implementation:*

```
 void funForCookie(int RandomValue) async {
   SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await pref.setInt("randomNumValuekey", RandomValue);
}
```

Then storing it in variable `RandomNumber` to pass it to my API as parameter:

`int? RandomNumber;`

```
 void getCred() async {  //======HERE WE FETCH OUR CREDENTIALS FROM SHARED PREF
   SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
    RandomNumber = pref.getInt("randomNumValuekey");
   });
```

[Add to cart Code snippet with api](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2222761)

[Cart screen snippets](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2222764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you `await` `funForCookie(Random().nextInt(90)+10)` before you call `getCred()`?

You are probably just missing the `await` keyword